# Can equivalent expressions yield different float results?

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy

The discussion to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4192724/algorithm-to-find-duplicate-in-an-array/4192823#4192823) just got me thinking about equality and equivalence of floating point numbers. I am aware that floating point numbers can not always be represented accurately. The question is, are there mathematically equivalent expressions that will yield different results when using floating point arithmetic? Can you provide an example?

**Edit:** Let me be more clear. I am aware that the same code with different compilers or different machines can return different results. What I am looking for are two mathematically equivalent expressions that I can compare in my Python interpreter/C++ program/Whatever and get an unexpected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> are there mathematically equivalent
>   expressions that will yield different
>   results when using floating point
>   arithmetic?

Absolutely. In fact, you should expect this to happen more often than not.

Even the same code [can yield different results](http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/28/14/29/PDF/floating-point-article.pdf) on different machines or compilers.

> Can you provide an example?

Sure. This Java code should repeatably yield two different results:

```
public strictfp class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        float a = 0.7f;
        float b = 0.3f;
        float c = 0.1f;

        float r1 = ((a * b) * c);
        float r2 = (a * (b * c));

        System.out.println(r1);
        System.out.println(r2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, compare e.g.

```
x = (a * b) / c;
```

with

```
x = a * (b / c);
```

Here's an example in C which demonstrates this:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    double a, b, c, x1, x2;

    a = sqrt((double)rand());
    b = sqrt((double)rand());
    c = sqrt((double)rand());

    x1 = (a * b) / c;
    x2 = a * (b / c);

    printf("a = %.20f\n", a);
    printf("b = %.20f\n", b);
    printf("c = %.20f\n", c);
    printf("x1 = %.20f\n", x1);
    printf("x2 = %.20f\n", x2);
    printf("x1 - x2 = %.20f\n", x1 - x2);

    return 0;
}
```

For me this gives the following results:

```
$ gcc -O3 -Wall math.c -o math
$ ./math
a = 129.64181424216494065149
b = 16807.00000000000000000000
c = 40282.13093916457728482783
x1 = 54.09073256970189902404
x2 = 54.09073256970190612947
x1 - x2 = -0.00000000000000710543
$
```

(Core i7, gcc 4.0.1, Mac OS X 10.6)

Note that in general you may get different results with any given expression and different CPU, compiler, compiler switches, math library, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try with multiplication and addition:

in pseudo-c code

```
float x = 1/7;
float y = x * 4;
float z = x + x + x + x;
if (y != z) {
    printf("oh noes!\n");
}
```

Comment: No, and it would probably only work on some compiler with some particular optimization flag.